# Linking a displayed MySQL result to a specific MySQL search

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database that a user can search using 5 different fields. The more information that is given the more specific the search becomes. However the less information that is given the broader the search is which in turn displays all the results for the given information. What I'm trying to do is when the information is displayed the user can click one of the results and it will give them all the information pertaining to that entry. What I need help with is how do I turn the clicked on information into a new specific SQL search and display all the information for that table row?

Comment: [Cool Story](http://th336.photobucket.com/albums/n326/nephila47/th_NiceStoryBro.jpg)... can you show what you have tried...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone..... love the animation effect. LOL

Comment: You use the same method that you use in step 1 to perform the search.

Comment: Why not bring back the whole result set and filter at the application level (e.g. with a bit of JavaScript(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well each record you display should have a link that a user can click on to go to a page with more detail.

`echo '<a href="info.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>';`

From there, get the `id` on `info.php`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . $_GET['id']);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['id'];
// echo any fields you want to display
}
```

This is just a guideline. You're open to sql injection.